# Partial Derivative of $f(t-k)$ with respect to $f(t)$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

How should I calculate the partial derivative
$$
\dfrac{\partial f(t-k)}{\partial f(t)}
$$
where $f(\cdot)$ is a scalar function and $k$ is an arbitrary non-zero constant?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure that that makes any sense. $f(t)$ is not one of the variables that $f(t-k)$ depends on. Even with ordinary derivatives, I'm not entirely certain that I know what this would mean.

Comment: So does it mean that the partial derivative should be zero since $f(t-k)$ does not depend on $f(k)$ at all?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that $$\dfrac{\partial g(t)}{\partial f(t)} = \frac{g'(t)}{f'(t)} $$ is a good definition. Now just apply this to $g(t) := f(t-k).$